# Frozen window when updating ItemsSource

Tags: c#, wpf, multithreading, telerik, itemssource

In my project I have a Telerik `Timeline` control into a `UserControl` along with other controls like `TextBlock, Border, Grid, StackPanel`, etc.
I add this `UserControl` to my `MainWindow` where I have other controls.

I need to update the `ItemsSource` of the `Timeline` control every 5 seconds to show new information that I receive from other process.

The problem is that when I am updating the `ItemsSource` the whole application freezes for a fraction of a second.

I tried to use a `BackgroundWorker` to obtain the new information and update the `ItemsSource` but with the same result.

At first I thought this was due to the time it takes to get the information from the server. But then I omitted the part where I assign the new `ItemsSource` to the controls and the application didn't freeze so I guess this happens when the `Timeline` control is updating its layout.

Is there a way to update the `ItemsSource` without freezing the whole window?

Thanks in advance.

Alberto

Comment: Updating the UI must be done on the UI thread, so it's not able to do anything else at the same time.  There's no way around that I'm afraid.  There may be a way to optimise what you're doing but we'd have to know specifics to be able to tell.

Comment: Updating a lot of graphics in WPF does typically take a noticeable amount of time, especially if you're binding all kinds of properties such as color and dimensions. If it really is terrible, then profile it and you might be able to find the bottleneck: I never used the timeline before but as an example the xceed grid that I was using was 'exceed'ingly slow because of the measure step. I fixed it by setting the row height to a constant value and the problem went away.

Comment: Yes, actually I am binding a lot of properties to customize the control, I can't use constant values because those values can change during the execution of the application. Right now I am going to use a profiler to see if I can optimize something.